# Why can't I click on windows in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

When I reinstalled GIMP, it ignored clicks on images, although I could click on menus or the toolbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the "Edit | Input preferences" dialogue, I had to choose "USB Mouse", then change "Mode" from "Disabled" to "Screen", then click "Save", then click "Close". Now the mouse works fine.